# Recovering data from Raw SD Card

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, usb, google-search, micro-sd-card

So I took a micro sd card out of my phone and when I try to reformat it it says windows was unable to reformat the sd card. Is there a way to refromat the sd card and saving the data afterwards.

Comment: we need to save data before format sd card. If not, you will lost your data after format. For format issue, i would suggest to format in Disk Management instead of file explorer. (Go to start\control panel\administrative tooks\computer management\Disk Management)

Answer (score 1):

You don't recover data AFTER you've formatted a storage device. You recover the data first.

However, your microSD card is likely dying. These cards will go into "read only mode" when they detect internal fault conditions indicative of their imminent failure. The correct thing to do is to copy all of the data off of the card now, and then destroy the card and replace it.